# How to add multiple line in ionic UIActionSheet?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, uiactionsheet

Need help on this, How do add multiple lines in ionic UIActionSheet? I tried add '/n' but it cannot work at detail.ts file.

```
    <ion-button expand="full" shape="round" class="ion-margin" *ngIf="facility.bookable" (click)="showSlots()">
          Booking Now
      </ion-button>


    public async showSlots() {
      const buttons = this.facility.slot.map((slot) => {
      if (slot.availability > 0) {
        let name = slot.name;
        if (slot.price !== '0.00') {
          name = `${name} - RM${slot.price}` + '\n' + `${slot.start_time} - ${slot.end_time}`;
        }

        return {
          text: name,
          handler: () => {
            this.bookingSlot(slot);
          }
        };
      }
    });

    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: 'Slots',
      buttons
    });

    await actionSheet.present();
 }
```

**Here is the example of current ui looks**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12RwK.png)

**This is the ui I wanna try to archive**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv52d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this [from what I see in the source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/bd96a81ff80ffe32914804ba9b6234c0286a33db/core/src/components/action-sheet/action-sheet-interface.ts#L24). As you can see from the source highlighted below, the ActionSheet Button accepts a string type.

```
export interface ActionSheetButton {
  text?: string;
  role?: 'cancel' | 'destructive' | 'selected' | string;
  icon?: string;
  cssClass?: string | string[];
  handler?: () => boolean | void | Promise<boolean | void>;
}
```

Have you considered trying something similar with the [modal component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal)? This would support your UX needs.